# N-th Taylor Polynomial

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Let $f$ and $f'$, $f''$, . . . , $f^{(n)}$ be continuous in a closed interval [$a, b$] containing a point $c$.
Write down the $n$-th Taylor polynomial of $f(x)$ around $x = c$.

So I know that the Taylor series is 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!} (x-a)^k = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+...+\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$$

Since this is worth only one mark, I was wondering do I just sub in $x=c$ or am I just not thinking right?

Comment: You sup $a=c$, also your summation has to go up to $n$ and not $\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial you are looking for reads:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{f^{(k)}(c)}{k!} (x-c)^k. $$

Comment: Thanks a lot Fred!